# Using a Wrapper on a class method in Python

Tags: python, class, wrapper

I'd like to be able to use a wrapper on a class method:

```
def wrapper(f):
def inner(*args,**kwargs):
    print 'inner '+f.__name__
    x = f(*args,**kwargs)
    return x
return inner

class A:
    @wrapper
    def f1(x=55):
       return x

print A().f1()
```

This returns <**main**.A instance at 0x05FF7530>

How can I return the result of the wrapped function A.f1()?

Comment: please fix the indentation

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten the self-argument:

```
class A:
    @wrapper
    def f1(self, x=55):
       return x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to call it as stated in the question, make it a `classmethod`:

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    @wrapper
    def f1(self, x=55):
       return x
>>> A.f1()
inner f1
55
>>>
```